# Modal window opening behind fade

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm generating dynamic links but when I click a link the modal window is opening behind the faded div so that I can't then click anything. Any idea how I can make it appear on top so that it can be closed?

Also how can I stop the page from jumping to top when clicking one of the links? I want the scroll position to stay the same so that you don't have to try and find out where you were on the page. Any help appreciated.

```
<script>
function showModal(el) {
jQuery("#myModalLabel").text(el.title);
jQuery("#myModal").modal()

 }

</script>

<a  href="#" id="mymodal" onclick="showModal(this)" style="font-size:16px;"  
title="<? echo  $row ['title']  ?> 
 by
<? echo $row ['author'] ?>" ><? echo $row ['first_line'] ?> </a>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
dismiss="modal">Close</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try setting [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) on the css-class.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Just needed to move outside containers to just before the closing body tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this one dude

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" id="yourModal" data-target="#myModal" data-title='<? echo  $row ["title"]  ?>  by <? echo $row ["author"] ?> '><? echo $row ['first_line'] ?></button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

javascript (jquery)

```
        <script>
     $(document).on("click", "#yourModal", function () {
        var title = $(this).data('title');
           $("#myModalLabel").val( title );
        });

    </script>
```